# Method that sums up all values from references model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

Group and Task (has name:string, point:integer, state:string (to_do,in_progress, done),group_id:integer)

Group has_many :tasks, and Task belongs_to Group.

I would like to write a method that sums up all tasks which has state:done for each group.

I tried to write it:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users
 has_many :tasks
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
 has_one :grade


 def amount_of_points
  amount = Object.tasks.point.where(state:"done")
  amount

 end
end
```

But it wont work. How to handle it ?

Comment: *sums up all tasks* You mean `count`?

Comment: Do you mean to sum tasks for the current group?

Comment: I mean sum point from task for the current group :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If you meant to *Sum of all tasks based on `point` for each group*</s> If you are trying to *get the **sum of points** for all tasks of each group*, then you can do

```
Task.includes(:group).where("state = ?", 'done').sum(:point)
```

Comment: How to modify it, to work for each group ? When I use this method above, it will show the same amount for every group, no matter if they have done they task or not ?

Comment: @Pigius you need to use `group` method